# "at a crossing point of 5" or "at a crossing point 5"

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a math statement in which two curves cross and I have defined the term "crossing point" as the value on the horizontal axis at which the two curves cross. Now suppose the crossing point is 5. In this case, which of the following should I say: the two curves cross (1) "at a crossing point of 5" (2) "at a crossing point 5" (3) "at the crossing point of 5" (4) "at the crossing point 5"

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what ***the crossing point is 5*** means here. Do you mean that you've got a couple of curves plotted ***on a chart***, and that ***5*** is the value of ***one of the chart axes*** at a point where the two curves intersect? If so, what about the value of the ***other*** axis?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good question. 5 is the value on the horizontal axis. In fact, before this statement in the paper, I have defined what is a "crossing point" but I did not make this clear when I asked the question here. I have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly natural in English (or in mathematics) to identify the intersection / crossing point by using the value of one of the axes "adjectivally". So really, the answer to your question should be *Don't try to do this anyway!* Is this the *only* point where the two plotted function values intersect? If so, it's just ***the** intersection*. If the plots intersect at several points, and you specifically want to focus on *that* one, you should probably identify it by something like *the intersection **at point x,y.***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for advice about a phrase which no English mathematician is likely to write.

Answer (score 2):

*At a crossing point 5* would lead me to look for a diagram in which a point was labelled "5": i.e., "5" would be the name or label of the point.

*At a crossing point of 5* I interpret as "at a point where something has the value 5".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.